# How to send a http 200 for an event request for Slack API in Python request

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

I need to respond to the event request with an HTTP 2xx. I am using the Request method in Python. How can I just return it? Please help.

My current problem is, I am using tunnelling software on my localhost. So for slack:

> Your app should respond to the event request with an HTTP 2xx within
>   three seconds. If it does not, we'll consider the event delivery
>   attempt failed. After a failure, we'll retry three times, backing off
>   exponentially.

I respond back to slack by this command

```
resp = requests.post(url,json=payload, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
data = resp.json()
status = data['status']
send_message = status
slack_client.api_call("chat.postMessage", channel=channel, text=send_message)
```

So now since I am not ending any response back in 3 seconds, its retries 3 times, so I am getting 4 responses back.

So as soon as I receive the request I need to respond back with Http2xx.

Comment: Please add your code here so we can help. What have you done so far? Do you have an API/server running to receive the request and return something?

Comment: @LucaBezerra, yes I am using ngrok for tunneling my localhost. The problem is since I am not respnding back immediately, there is a delay of more than 3 seconds, because of which Slack retry thrice. So I get 3 response.

Comment: Please add the relevant part of your code to the question. Are you using flask? If so please add the tag.

Comment: added @ErikKalkoken

Comment: yeah this will not work. you need to terminate your current script in order to send a http 200 back and open a new thread or process to continue your app

Comment: I can post an example if you like

Comment: sure that will be of great help @ErikKalkoken

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197698/discussion-between-wanderors-and-erik-kalkoken).

Comment: Hey @wanderors did you end up getting this sorted out. I think I'm having the same problem you are having, and I can't for the life of me figure out how to send a 200 message back to slack to prevent it from retrying.

Answer (score 3):

In order to respond to a request with HTTP 200 you need to first spawn a 2nd process or thread to continue execution of the app and then terminate the primary thread / process.

There are many ways to do it, here is a complete example with threading and Flask.

It's receiving a slash command request from Slack, responds immediately with a short message. Then waiting 7 seconds to simulate heavy processing and finally responding with a message again.

This example is working with slash commands, but the approach works for events too.

```
import threading
from time import sleep
from flask import Flask, json, request
import requests

app = Flask(__name__) #create the Flask app

@app.route('/slash', methods=['POST'])
def slash_response():                
    """endpoint for receiving all slash command requests from Slack"""

    # get the full request from Slack
    slack_request = request.form

    # starting a new thread for doing the actual processing    
    x = threading.Thread(
            target=some_processing,
            args=(slack_request,)
        )
    x.start()

    ## respond to Slack with quick message
    # and end the main thread for this request
    return "Processing information.... please wait"

def some_processing(slack_request):
    """function for doing the actual work in a thread"""

    # lets simulate heavy processing by waiting 7 seconds
    sleep(7)

    # response to Slack after processing is finished
    response_url = slack_request["response_url"]    
    message = {        
        "text": "We found a result!"
    }
    res = requests.post(response_url, json=message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=8000) #run app in debug mode on port 8000
```